# How to debug it in mobile safari and ios simulator?

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, mobile-safari

I have this problem with bootstrap tokenfield. The suggestion box  (containing the text in black color) is not responding to user click. That means I am not able to get the value `abc@gmail.com` from tokenfield. Instead I am left with the initial user input letter `a`. It only happens in mobile safari and I am able to reproduce the problem in iOS simulator.

What I found extremely difficult to debug is the fact that the suggestion box is created dynamically. The moment I use 'Develop' of Safari to select this element in iOS simulator, the suggestion box has already disappeared.

What is the best strategy to debug in this situation? Is there any way I can *pin* the element for example?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the JavaScript debugger to set a breakpoint where you try to read the contents (or if that doesn't work, perhaps a watch condition). Stopping at a breakpoint will essentially freeze the user interface as-is and you can then easily inspect it.

To learn more about the WebKit debugger and how to set breakpoints, see [this Safari documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Debugger/Debugger.html).

Comment: Thanks. I think it is also important to know where to set a break point. Eventually setting breakpoints to 'blur' event helps me to locate the root cause

Comment: Great to hear! Yes, it's a bit tricky. If you do it often enough you'll get the hang of it. :)